# Combining logic in subsetting

Tags: r, subset

If I am sub-setting using logical statements, is there a way of combining without using logical operators? i.e. is there a more effective way of doing the following:

```
train$TOD[train$Hour == 23 | train$Hour == 0 | train$Hour == 1 | train$Hour == 2]
```

Comment: Try `train$TOD[ train$Hour %in% c(23,0,1 2) ]`

Comment: If you are using devel version of `data.table`, `library(data.table);setDT(train, key='Hour')[.(c(23,0,1,2)), TOD]`

Answer (score 0):

With a reproducible example it could be great but I think that this code is what you are looking for:

```
train[train$Hour %in% c(0, 1, 2, 23), ]
```

Comment: You are welcome, but just a reminder for next time: help users to help you by providing a ***reproducible* example. Here you can find useful informations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example